unable to debug unit test cases in intellij
I am trying to debug the test cases in intellij, when I put a breakpoint and try to run the case in debug mode. I am just getting a build output and error saying
Process 'Gradle Test Executor 42' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Can you provide [mcve]?
